# Django-Differentiate between verified and non verified users in database via email confirmation link

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I want to differentiate between the users who signed up and are verified through email confirmation link, and those who signed up but not verified through email confirmation.

I tried `is_active` and `is_authenticated` but did not got the desired results.

Comment: by adding `is_email_verified` columns to your model indicate the difference between your users.

Comment: how to add `is_email_verified` columns

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new field is an okay solution if you have a custom user model or some secondary model to store addition user information. If you don't have any of this and you are not planning to add them then just use groups.

First create a group called Email Verified. You can do this via django admin or via data migration.

```
Group.objects.create(name='Email Verified')
```

Then to mark users as email verified you can do

```
email_verified_group = Group.objects.get(name='Email Verified')
the_user.groups.add(email_verified_group)
```

To check if the user is email verified or not

```
is_email_verified = the_user.groups.filter(name='Email Verified').exists()
```